# Python - how to pass variables in another variables

Tags: python

I'm trying to pass data of two variables into another variable but I'm getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "poll_azure_devops_audit_log.py", line 28, in <module>
    x = requests.request('GET', URL, proxies=PROXIES, auth=AZURE_AUTH).json()
  File "/opt/splunk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, kwargs)
  File "/opt/splunk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 519, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/opt/splunk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/opt/splunk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 317, in prepare
    self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
  File "/opt/splunk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 548, in prepare_auth
    r = auth(self)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

How do I have to pass the variables USER & PASSWORD into variable AZURE_AUTH?

```
 import sys
    import requests
    import json
    from urllib.parse import quote
    from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
    
    ORGANIZATION = 'xxx'
    CONTINUATIONTOKEN = None
    API_ENDPOINT = 'https://auditservice.dev.azure.com/'
    USER = 'xxx'
    PASSWORD = 'xxx'
    AZURE_AUTH = HTTPBasicAuth('user123', 'password123')
    
    
    URL = API_ENDPOINT + ORGANIZATION + '/_apis/audit/auditlog?api-version=6.1-preview&skipAggregation=true'
    PROXIES = {
            'http' : 'http://xxx:8080',
            'https' : 'https://xxx:8080',
     }
    
    
    print(URL)
    print(AZURE_AUTH)
    print(USER)
    print(PASSWORD)
    print(PROXIES)
    
    x = requests.request('GET', URL, proxies=PROXIES, auth=AZURE_AUTH).json()
    print (x)
```

Comment: Maybe something like this: ```AZURE_AUTH = HTTPBasicAuth(USER, PASSWORD)```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you think you have is not the problem you actually have. To pass USER and PASSWORD to `HTTPBasicAuth` is done like this:

```
AZURE_AUTH = HTTPBasicAuth(USER, PASSWORD)
```

and you can assign any value you want to your USER and PASSWORD variables like this :

```
USER = 'user123'
PASSWORD = 'password123'
```

If you get an error it is comming from somewhere else